# What class is responsible for recording sound in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, programming-languages, counter, decibel

I wanted to make a decibel counter for the iPhone, but don't know what class is responsible for recording sound.

Answer (score 1):

It's the AVAudioRecorder. You need to add the AVFoundation.framework to your project to use the class.